# What does "charter subscriber" mean in this sentence? (It's from the movie "Gone Girl" by David Fincher)

Tags: meaning

"I happen to be a charter subscriber to middling warlord weekly."
(He was guessing what she does for a living and she gave him three ABC options and one of them was that she's a moderately influential warlord :))

Answer (score 1):

A charter subscriber is someone who was an original or early subscriber to a publication, and who (normally) receives acknowledgement and benefits because of that. It derives from the sense of a [charter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charter) as a document founding something and setting out the rights and duties.

A [charter member](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/charter-member) is a founding member of an organisation, club, society, etc: someone who was in there from the beginning and contributed to getting it started. The phrase "charter subscriber" is similar: it refers to someone who took out an early subscription and has their contribution acknowledged by the publication. Various organisations offer a "charter subscriber" membership level for people who subscribed early with various benefits.

Here are some examples: [The Sun magazine](https://www.thesunmagazine.org/issues/3/become-a-charter-subscriber-issue-3) looking for charter subscribers to fund it becoming a regular publication. [Criterion video](https://www.criterion.com/current/posts/6277-got-questions-about-the-criterion-channel) has a scheme for long-standing members. If you search for the phrase you will find more.

Comment: That was a very comprehensive explanation :) Thank You :*